# I am able to upload the csv file on the server but its not displaying in the main panel or in the shiny dashboard body panel

Tags: shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

I am developing a web application using shiny App and I am new to shiny and dashboards that can be used for the building of the App. I have taken an example of uploading data to the server but after uploading I am not able to view in the main panel or dashboard area.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = strong ("OMNALYSIS")),
  dashboardSidebar(fileInput("file1", "Upload Expression Data",
                                accept = c(
                                  "text/csv",
                                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                                  ".csv"),

  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tableOutput("contents")

  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {`enter code here`
  output$contents <- renderTable({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)

    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I expected to view the csv-file uploaded by the user to the main panel or the space of shiny dashboard.

> > error - Warning: Error in !: invalid argument type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variable `input$header` but it wasn't created. I would suggest to remove the `input$header` in the server, or create `input$header` in the UI.

Remove it from server:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = strong ("OMNALYSIS")),
  dashboardSidebar(fileInput("file1", "Upload Expression Data",
                             accept = c(
                               "text/csv",
                               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                               ".csv")
                             
  )),
  dashboardBody(
    tableOutput("contents")
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {#'enter code here'
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath)
  })
}   
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Add it to the UI :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = strong ("OMNALYSIS")),
  dashboardSidebar(fileInput("file1", "Upload Expression Data",
                             accept = c(
                               "text/csv",
                               "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                               ".csv")),
  checkboxInput("header", "Header")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tableOutput("contents")
    
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {#'enter code here'
  output$contents <- renderTable({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
    read.csv(inFile$datapath, header = input$header)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @gdevaux, Its working now, I want to ask one more question which one is better shiny dashboard or flexdashboard to build an web application? Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't used flexdashboard yet so I can't compare. If the anwser is ok to you, you can consider clicking it as "accepted".